# Filtering DataWeave expression works in DataWeave Playground but not in Anypoint Studio - why?

Tags: xml, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I was working on DataWeave expression with filters, which worked fine in DataWeave Playground (dwlang), but it doesn't work when executed in Anypoint Studio (it doesn't filter anything).

I have an XML payload, which I need to transform to another XML, but I am using filters to get needed output.
This is example of my XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <id>4716835902187396</id>
        <rowNumber>1</rowNumber>
        <expanded>true</expanded>
        <createdAt>2023-02-01T09:31:38Z</createdAt>
        <modifiedAt>2023-02-01T09:31:43Z</modifiedAt>
        <cells>
            <columnId>5092563453011844</columnId>
            <value>New Sold-to</value>
            <displayValue>New Sold-to</displayValue>
        </cells>
        <cells>
            <columnId>2840763639326596</columnId>
            <value>49908602</value>
            <displayValue>49908602</displayValue>
        </cells>
    </row>
</rows>
```

The DataWeave expression which I am using looks like this:

```
root: { requestType: (payload.rows.row.*cells filter ($.columnId =="5092563453011844")).value,
        number: (payload.rows.row.*cells filter ($.columnId =="2840763639326596")).value}
```

In the DataWeave playground, I got the desired result, so in this case it is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <requestType>New Sold-to</requestType>
  <number>49908602</number>
</root>
```

However, the expression doesn't work in Anypoint studio, it doesn't extract any value, so I get only empty XML file (empty tags). Where could be the problem?

I found [similar article](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005OcRdgSAF/why-does-dataweave-work-in-dwlang-but-not-in-studio), however, the workaround with using "When" would not work for me, since there is far more elements I am working with (it can be around 70), not just the 2 listed here. I am using Mule 4.4.0.

Comment: You may be getting a different payload then what you are using in the dataweave playground. I will recommend you to try to run the app in debug mode and [Evaluate your dataweave sing an Expression](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.5/to-evaluate-breakpoint-using-expression). Try to give a small part of dataweave without filter and see if that gives some results

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please tell us which version of Mule are you using. `when` is for Mule 3.x only.

Comment: @HarshankBansal I have tried that, it gives results without filter.
@aled I have Mule 4.4.0 (updated it in my post as well). For the `when` I just assumed that it would not work anyway.